# Is is possible to use datastore_export_operator in Airflow to export Firestore backup?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, airflow, google-cloud-composer

While the datastore_export_operator is available with Airflow (running on Cloud Composer), it is possible to use the operator to run a scheduled Firestore export (in native mode)?

While new to Airflow/Composer, I tried using the datastore_export_operator to run an export on Cloud Composer but received an error.

```
INFO - Subtask: googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://datastore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/[REDACTED]:export?alt=json returned "The caller does not have permission">
```

Is it right to assume that Cloud Composer would use the default GCP service account? If so, does it mean that the Datastore operator does not work with native Firestore? Are there other ways to run the export?

Comment: If you are using the default connections, looks like it is using the service account associated with your environment [link](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/connections)

Comment: Thanks ECris. The default connection works. I found that permission has to be granted explicitly (instead of by default) for this in IAM.